# DateTime local and utc the same

Tags: c#

I am sending from webbrowser this string `"2019-01-25T00:00:00+01:00"`
I undestand this as: this is local time and in utc should be `"2019-01-24T23:00:00"`

but on the server :

```
myDate.Kind is local
myDate "2019-01-24T23:00:00"
myDate.ToLocalTime() is the same "2019-01-24T23:00:00"
myDate.ToUniversalTime() is the same "2019-01-24T23:00:00"
```

what I need is if I sent this string `"2019-01-25T00:00:00+01:00"` I need to know on the server that there is 1h difference between local and utc

and parsing this string is done automatically by dot net core api (DateTime is method parameter)

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve]. _The key is understanding how **exactly** you are sending that date to the server._

Comment: How do you convert / parse from `"2019-01-25T00:00:00+01:00"` initial `string` into `myDate` (`DateTime`)?

Comment: In order to avoid confusion and bugs with datetime you could have all datetime values in app in either `UTC` format or `timestamp` such as `unix timestamp`. It might seem a bit complicated at first but it will begin to pay off very soon...

Comment: What if you provide *Zulu*, i.e. `"2019-01-24T23:00:00Z"` string? Is the server's date correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `DateTime` Type does not have any concept of time zones: if you need this, use `DateTimeOffset` instead.

I suspect your server is in the UTC timezone, Since ToLocalTime and ToUniversalTime give the same result.

Comment: I was curious, so I tried on [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/IUQjLk) and it works like expected. So, changing the Types to DateTimeOffset in our API should actually give you the wished behavior.

Answer (score 1):

You can try `AdjustToUniversal` option, e.g.

```
  string source = "2019-01-25T00:00:00+01:00";

  DateTime myDate = DateTime.ParseExact(
    source, 
   "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:sszzz", 
    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, 
    DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal);

  Console.Write(string.Join(Environment.NewLine,
    $"Value = {myDate:HH:mm:ss}",
    $"Kind  = {myDate.Kind}"));
```

**Outcome:**

```
  Value = 23:00:00 
  Kind  = Utc
```

**Edit:** If you can't change server's code and thus you have to provide a `string` (`source`) such that `DateTime.Parse(source)` 
will return a correct date you can try to convert existing time-zone (`+01:00`) into *Zulu*:

```
  string source = "2019-01-25T00:00:00+01:00";

  // 2019-01-24T23:00:00Z
  source = DateTime
    .ParseExact(source,
               "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:sszzz",
                CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal)
    .ToString("yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss'Z'");
```

Then on the server you'll have

```
 // source is treated as UTC-time;
 // However, by default (when no options provided) myDate will have Kind = Local
 DateTime myDate = DateTime.Parse(source);

 Console.Write(string.Join(Environment.NewLine,
   $"Value = {myDate:HH:mm:ss}",
   $"Kind  = {myDate.Kind}"));
```

**Outcome:**

```
 Value = 02:00:00 // May vary; adjusted to server's time zone (In my case MSK: +03:00)
 Kind  = Local    // DateTime.Parse returns Local when no options specified
```