# Why local datetime has the same timestamp with utc datetime, no matter its DateTime or DateTImeOffset?

Tags: c#, datetime, time, utc

I have checked this question [DateTime local and utc the same](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54457769/datetime-local-and-utc-the-same), but still have no idea.

Here's my code

```cs
DateTime localNow = DateTime.Now;
DateTime utcNow = DateTime.UtcNow;
Int64 localTimeStamp = ((DateTimeOffset)localNow).ToUnixTimeSeconds();
Int64 utcTimeStamp = ((DateTimeOffset)utcNow).ToUnixTimeSeconds();

Console.WriteLine("With Datetime");
Console.WriteLine("Current time: " + localNow.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss") + " timestamp: " + localTimeStamp);
Console.WriteLine("Current Utc time: " + utcNow.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss") + " timestamp: " + utcTimeStamp);

DateTimeOffset localNowOff = DateTimeOffset.Now;
DateTimeOffset utcNowOff = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow;
Int64 localOffTimeStamp = localNowOff.ToUnixTimeSeconds();
Int64 utcOffTimeStamp = utcNowOff.ToUnixTimeSeconds();
Console.WriteLine("With DatetimeOffset");
Console.WriteLine("Current time: " + localNowOff.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss") + " timestamp: " + localOffTimeStamp);
Console.WriteLine("Current Utc time: " + utcNowOff.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss") + " timestamp: " + utcOffTimeStamp);
```

And heres' the output:

```cs
With Datetime
Current time: 2023/10/31 23:11:33 timestamp: 1698765093
Current Utc time: 2023/10/31 15:11:33 timestamp: 1698765093

With DatetimeOffset
Current time: 2023/10/31 23:11:33 timestamp: 1698765093
Current Utc time: 2023/10/31 15:11:33 timestamp: 1698765093
```

I don't believe the timestamp result between local ant utc should be the same, but it did happen.

However, when i try get local datetime from the timestamp, it turns out to be utc datetime, like this:

```cs
DateTime localNow = DateTime.Now;
Int64 localTimeStamp = ((DateTimeOffset)localNow).ToUnixTimeSeconds();
DateTime localDateTime = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Local);
localDateTime = localDateTime.AddSeconds(localTimeStamp).ToLocalTime();
Console.WriteLine("Convert local timestamp to datetime: " + localDateTime.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss"));
```

So am i doing anything wrong and what's the proper way to get the timestamp about local time and utc time and convert back to datetime?

Comment: "I don't believe the timestamp result between local ant utc should be the same, but it did happen." Why not? What makes you think they'd be different? From the documentation: "This method first converts the current instance to UTC before returning its Unix time." A timestamp represents an instant in time - and `DateTimeOffset.Now` and `DateTimeOffset.UtcNow` both represent the same instant in time.

Comment: A timestamp is just a point in time. Let's say we measure a moment when a metor collapsed on earth. Depending on where in the world you are at that moment the local time is different. Maybe it was day in Australia and night in Canada. Still it is the same moment in time.

Comment: Unix time is always UTC, trying to get a "local" timestamp doesn't make sense.  If you need a single number to represent time then consider the Ticks or TotalSeconds property, perhaps after subtracting an epoch date.

Comment: Sorry for replying so late and Thanks for you guys answers. I did need to read the documentation first.  Before i used to believe the method will auto calc the offset about timezone and apply to the result for timestamp, but now i realize the problems it will cause. Great thanks! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no local unix timestamp as the epoch unix timestamp is always UTC+0.

If you want to convert the timestamp to local do something like this:

```cs
DateTimeOffset dt = DateTimeOffset.FromUnixTimeSeconds(1698766249);
DateTime localDt = dt.LocalDateTime;
```

Comment: Now i get it, thanks for your help!

Comment: @Hellagur Feel free to hit that thumbs up or drop the coveted check mark if my answer hit the bullseye for you! Happy to assist. Cheers!